# How to get external faces from a vtk file?

Tags: python, c++, c, vtk

I have a cube made of hexaedrons and I want to get all the external faces (of the hexaedrons, not the "big" cube) but I'm not able to do it. I think the best way is to iterate over all faces and get the ones that don't have adjacent faces, don't know if this is the correct way. My code is in python but answers in both C/C++ and python are welcome

```
    # Read the source file.
    reader = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridReader()
    reader.SetFileName(file_name)
    reader.Update()
    
    output = reader.GetOutput()
    points = output.GetPoints()
    
    # get faces
    faces = []
    for i in range(output.GetNumberOfCells()):
        cell = output.GetCell(i)
        #print(type(cell)) hexaedron
        cell_points_ids = []
        for face_index in range(cell.GetNumberOfFaces()):
            a=vtk.reference([0,0,0,0])
            cell.GetFaceToAdjacentFaces(face_index,a)
```

**Update**

```
gf = vtk.vtkGeometryFilter()
gf.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
gf.Update()
polydata_output = gf.GetOutput()

print(polydata_output.GetNumberOfCells()) # 291024
print(output.GetNumberOfCells()) #48504
```

**Update 2**

```
sc = vtk.vtkStaticCleanUnstructuredGrid()
sc.Update()
sc.SetInputData(output)

sc.Update()
gf = vtk.vtkGeometryFilter()
sc_output = sc.GetOutput()
gf.SetInputData(sc_output)
#gf.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
gf.Update()
polydata_output = gf.GetOutput()

print(polydata_output.GetNumberOfCells()) # 19120
print(output.GetNumberOfCells()) #48504
```

[image: cube inside]

Comment: Why do people forget to add Java, Fortran and Basic to the language list?  If you are going to tag more than one, you might as well edit your post with all the languages.  Don't ask for answers in other languages, as they may be incomprehensible or incompatible with the language you are programming in.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have added just C/C++ because i know it a little, while java and the others just by name and if I'm not wrong many people use C/C++ when working with vtk. So maybe someone know the answer in c but not in python. Anyway you are correct, some answers may be incompatible

Comment: I'm glad you know C/C++ a little because it is not a language.  The C++ language allows for operator overloading, access specifiers and namespaces.  The C language doesn't support those.  What will you do if I answer your issue in LISP or Algol?
If you are writing a program in Python, ask for results in Python.  If your issue is language agnostic, remove all language tags.

Comment: Maybe it's more accurate to say that I know a little of C++, not so much to know the difference between it and C. Anyway answers in any language, also pseudocode, can help. They can be helpful to understand at least the logic behind the solution I'm looking for and I'm afraid that someone just because doesn't know python and see the python tag doesn't respond. Probably it's better to accept answers in any language that is "similar" to python, not just c or c++. (For "similar" i mean any language that can be easily understood from someone who knows python)

Answer (score 1):

The [`vtkGeometryFilter`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkGeometryFilter.html#details) will extract `All 2D faces that are used by only one 3D cell`.
(I pointed the native Cxx API doc but python API is quite the same)

Comment: Thanks, probably that's really what I was looking for, but for some reason the filter "doesn't work". When I see the filtered output it still has all the faces, not only the surface, what's wrong with the code (I added the new code in the question)? Also the number of cells is bigger and not smaller, this confuses me

Comment: oh, I see : every face is extracted. I think it is because of duplicated points. Try to [clean](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkStaticCleanUnstructuredGrid.html) it before.

Comment: Thanks again, we're getting closer! You can see the result in the question (i have made a second update). There are still some internal faces, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Cannot say more.. Maybe dependent on your dataset. Try to `SetTolerance` on the clean filter ?